# How to hide data in a series in highcharts boxplot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I have a boxplot chart made with highcharts, and I have 2 series, one for the observations and one for the outliers. I want to hide one column in both of the series, but [going through the API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.data) there doesn't seem to be a way to hide a data row, you can only remove one. Is there a way to do it with the API rather than having to hack my way around it?

Edit: Some examples on the structure:

```
series: [{
 name: 'Observations',
 data: [{
    x: 0,
    low: 4,
    q1: 9,
    median: 9,
    q3: 1,
    high: 10,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
 }, {
    x: 1,
    low: 5,
    q1: 7,
    median: 3,
    q3: 6,
    high: 2,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
 }]},
 {
  name: 'Outliers',
  type: 'scatter',
  data: [
   [0, 2],
   [1, 5]
  ]
 }
]
```

This structure has 2 series, with the first series having the boxes  of the boxplot, and the second having the outliers. In other graphs, like the column graph, you can add each column as a `series`, which gives me more options to manipulate them, but here I have each column as a `data` array object. In Highcharts you can hide series by triggering the `hide()` function on the series, but you can't hide `data` objects, you can only remove them. What I want to do is hide a single data array object from rendering in the view.

As a workaround I can technically remove the object I want from `data` array and save it somewhere else, until I need it, but what I'm wondering is whether there's a better way of doing that, maybe using `plotPoints` or any other way.

[Here's also a demo from the highcharts website.](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot) The data here are an array, but anything in the [data API above](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.data) still work on them. Here's the [series api](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot) for comparison.

Comment: Hi @amouda, Could you describe your problem more precisely? Also, some live example would be very useful.

Comment: @ppotaczek I added some more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. There are apparently 2 alternative ways to setup a Boxplot chart using series (which you can hide and show using the legend or the `hide()` and `show()` methods):

```
series: [{
 name: 'Series 1',
 data: [{
    x: 0,
    low: 4,
    q1: 9,
    median: 9,
    q3: 1,
    high: 10,
    name: "Point x1",
    color: "#00FF00"
 }, {
  type: 'scatter', 
  data: [[0, 1], [0,2]] // outlier points
 }]},
 {
  name: 'Series 2',
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    low: 5,
    q1: 7,
    median: 3,
    q3: 6,
    high: 2,
    name: "Point x2",
    color: "#FF00FF"
 }]
 // no outliers here
 }
]
```

Basically you can put Observations and Outliers in one series/column, by giving the outliers `type: 'scatter'` as shown above. The problem with this method is that you still can't hide the outliers for some reason by calling the `hide()` and `show()` methods.

The alternative way of doing this is putting each column observations and each outlier observations in a separate series, and giving both the same `x` value (the outliers should have the x of the box, in this example it's 0):

```
series: [{
 name: 'Series 1',
 data: [{
    x: 0,
    low: 4,
    q1: 9,
    median: 9,
    q3: 1,
    high: 10,
    name: "Point x1",
    color: "#00FF00"
 }]},
 {
  type: 'scatter', 
  name: 'Series 2: Outliers',
  data: [[0, 1], [0,2]]
 }
 {
  name: 'Series 3',
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    low: 5,
    q1: 7,
    median: 3,
    q3: 6,
    high: 2,
    name: "Point x2",
    color: "#FF00FF"
 }]
 }
]
```

To stack the observations and outliers over each other you have to disable grouping in the options:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can borrow `setVisible` method from `pointClass` in `pie` series prototype:

```
var pieSetVisible = Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible,
    point1 = chart.series[0].points[0],
    point2 = chart.series[1].points[0];

pieSetVisible.call(point1);
pieSetVisible.call(point2);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ahckoLn5/

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors with this solution: the first is `points is undefined`, and when I initialize an empty points array in my options/series (while adding my data), I'm getting another error `Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined  at setVisible` . I'm using Angular and Typescript just for clarification.

Comment: @amouda - To use this solution, you need to get a chart reference. Please provide me with some live example (codesandbox or stackblitz) if you want me to help you.

Comment: I took a break from this issue and came back to it. I was apparently changing information on the options object instead of the chart instance, but I finally found how to access the chart instance. 

The setVisible method works, but it leaves a hole in the graph. I want to hide the data like how a series hides it, when for example you click on the legend item. I found a workaround. I'll update my OP with the solution.

Comment: Hi @amouda, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor so that I can help you?

Comment: I managed to find a solution, I posted it in another thread reply here. But thank you!